# Arquillian Graphene waitModel TimeoutException lets test end with Error instead of Failure

Tags: java, selenium, junit, jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone

I think my issue has nothing to do with code but with waiting for UI-Elements in tests in general or at least my understanding of testing UIs with JUnit and Selenium/Arquillian Graphene.

When using Arquillian Graphenes waitModel() (or any of the other methods waiting for UI-Elements) and the element is not present after the specified timeout, I get a seleniumTimeoutException, which lets my JUnit-Test end with an "Error".

```
ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 151.709 s <<< FAILURE! - in de.viasurance.UiTest
[ERROR] testHappyPath(org.test1.UiTest)  Time elapsed: 23.266 s  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException:
```

Is there a better way to let the test end with a "Failure" without surrounding every single line of my test with a try/catch-block like this:

```
try {
waitModel().withMessage("waiting for loginButton").until().element(loginButton).is().clickable();
} catch (TimeoutException timeoutException) {
fail("UI-Test failed because the following UI-element could not be found: \n" + timeoutException.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Doesn't your `try-catch {}` provide you expected results?

Comment: The thing is, that nearly all test cases look like this. I wait for an Element to be present and then i click it. If i surrounded every single one of the 1000 lines of my test cases with a try/catch block. It would quickly become 5000 lines and 80% boilerplate code. If i surround the whole test with a try/catch then when a test fails, you cannot see which line makes the test fail.

Comment: Logic is pretty simple. If you can design your _testcase/usecase_ with proper waiter e.g. `waitModel()` your job is cut short. If you tend to fall back on `try-catch {}` for safety a _boilerplate code_ may be created.

Answer (score 0):

You do NOT have to surround this with a try/catch block and fail in the catch block

That should be taken care by your test framework itself. TestNG does a good job here.

```
Graphene.waitModel()
        .withMessage("Login Button Not clickable")
        .until()
        .element(loginButton)
        .is()
        .clickable();
```

For Junit, You could use [TestWatcher](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestWatcher.html) to detect the error and fail accordingly.